# How can I get sum of Items from one table to another in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get sum of items from one table to another in sql

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use join and subquery

```
   select p.*,stock from theProduct p
    join ( select prodcode,sum(Qty) as stock from thePurchaseDetail group by prodcode) t
      on p.prodcode=t.prodcode
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
select p.*, pp.stock 
from theProduct p cross apply
     (select sum(pp.qty) as stock 
      from thePurchaseDetail pp
      where pp.prodcode = p.prodcode
     ) pp;
```

You can also use window function with `JOIN` :

```
select p.*, sum(pp.qty) over (partition by p.prodcode) as stock
from theProduct p inner join
     thePurchaseDetail pp
     on pp.prodcode = p.prodcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would left join in case there are missing prodcodes in tblPurchaseDetail table

```
    select p.*
          ,t.stock 
     from tblProduct p
left join ( select prodcode
                  ,sum(Qty) as stock 
             from tblPurchaseDetail 
            group by prodcode
           ) t
      on p.prodcode=t.prodcode
```